# Count outlook emails with specific text in PowerBi

Tags: powerbi

I have linked outlook with Powerbi desktop. I can see all my mails in a table. I want to show the count of all the emails matching a particular text. I have added a card with a measure using Calculate(countrows) formula but it show Blank instead of the correct count. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Update](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77713284/edit) your question with the expression used for your measure.